# How to generate PDF in Puppeteer that are scaled to the device emulated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, automation, puppeteer

I have a HTML file that is written only for phone-screens and is sparse for web-browser screen sizes. 
I want to convert it to PDF via puppeteer. I have emulated iphoneX as my device inside puppeteer. 
If I do page.screenshot it works fine but while doing page.pdf I don't get the pdf scaled for an iPhone. 
here's the code.

```
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.emulate(iPhonex);
            await page.setContent(html);
            fileBuffer = await page.pdf({
                format: 'A4'
            });
```